# MySQL 8.0.31 INNODB table hangs on copy to tmp table when doing ALTER TABLE to add Column

Tags: mysql, freeze

UPDATE 11.15.2022
Per the request of Wilson Hauck,I have added text files showing the results of the following queries:

- SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free)
  FROM information_schema.tables; (https://pastebin.com/uHG0MynW)
- SHOW STATUS;  (https://pastebin.com/kJd3Pq6J)
- SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; (https://pastebin.com/51M84TBR)
- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; (https://pastebin.com/p7YsSDA2)
- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
- CREATE for table person_history_work (https://pastebin.com/HQSrBcXH)
- SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "person_history_work"; (https://pastebin.com/nyA5uQUw)

NOTE SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS is blank. Fields are empty.

---

This is on a Win 10 x64 system M.2 SSD with 500GB free and 5.3GHz CPU (32GB RAM).

I was going to add a column to an existing table (200MB in size with 300,000 rows) and the MySQL IDE hung. SHOW PROCESSLIST shows it stuck with the state of "copy to tmp table" on:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN columnname TEXT DEFAULT NULL
```

Looking in the MySQL data directory, these 4 files are constantly shuffling and being updated (as date modified) but never change in size:

[image: MYSQL Files]

I've restarted MySQL, and even updated to 8.0.31. This is an INNODB table I've never had an issue with before.

I did change my @@tmp_table_size to 700MB (it was 70MB). No effect.
I also changed @@buffer_pool_size to 1GB. No effect.

Here's the benchmarks of my SSD:
[image]

So right now I'm stuck, unable to ALTER the table. I can query, select, and look at the data no problem.

Only way to stop this is to KILL the process or restart the MySQL service. I've waited more than 20 minutes to no avail. Given the fact the file sizes don't change at all, it makes me think MySQL is stuck/hung. Since it's InnoDB I can't really repair - STATUS shows the table as fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: A 200MB table isn't large by modern standards, so it should finish copying within seconds. I suspect the server is overloaded, or else the storage is having trouble keeping up. You don't say if this is Linux or Windows or Mac. What type of disk is the datadir on? Do you have I/O metrics to check if it's straining?

Comment: Also the undo tablespaces should be unrelated. Those are likely to be used frequently for DML and then later for garbage collection, but DDL like ALTER TABLE doesn't use them.

Comment: Hey @BillKarwin. I updated the task: This is on a Win 10 x64 system M.2 SSD with 500GB free and 5.3GHz CPU (32GB RAM). Yah none of this really makes sense. My SSD is in good health; no errors (system is 1.5 years old). Not sure what else it could be...

Comment: I'd run some I/O throughput tests using a benchmarking tool, to try to see if the disk has performance problems regardless of MySQL. Unfortunately I can't recommend a tool. I don't use Windows.

Comment: @BillKarwin posted the benchmarks of my SSD in the OP. Are there any diagnostics I can run on the database or MySQL as a whole?

Comment: Additional DB information request for configuraton analysis (gathered when stuck), please  
# cores on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please also post TEXT results for the table you are trying to add a TEXT column, A) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "table_name"; for consideration.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have added the content you requested above.

Comment: You mentioned you updated your MySQL. I had a similar issue when upgraded MySQL. It just started to lag with no reason. Fixed only after full clean reinstall. Nothing helped.

Comment: @Floobinator Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE person_history_work; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "person_history_work";  workload analysis is in process.  Will try to finish in 48 hours.

Comment: @Floobinator  Observation, many people would not install a version of MySQL with less than 90 days since General Availability.  This is typically done to avoid being the person to find a problem that was not discovered in testing - to avoid reporting and waiting on corrective action or workaround discovery - unless you are willing to make this investment of time.  Your 8.0.31 went GA on 2022-10-11 - just over 1 month ago.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I only installed 8.0.31 locally because I had 8.0.30 installed and wanted to seed if the latest version impacted this issue. I usually only upgrade after 3-6 months.

Comment: Excellent thought on avoiding being the first to find a problem.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have provided the information you requested above.

Answer (score 0):

Observations may help you avoid stall/hanging,

Your SHOW CREATE TABLE person_history_work includes a line

AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 81,

consider removing this line because SHOW TABLE STATUS indicates ARL is 727.

In your my.ini consider

```
max_heap_table_size=734003200  # from 16M to match tmp_table_size - best practice
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of SSD IOPS capacity
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # to clear EXTENT activity reducing innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty ASAP
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=0.00001  # from 10% to reduce IBP-pages-dirty of 17,348
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0.00001  # from 90% to reduce dirty-pages overhead faster.
max_allowed_packet=256M  # from 4M to reduce # packets handled
```

Please view profile for contact info.  Additional global variables need to be adjusted.